# Await inside For Loop not working in initState function

Tags: flutter

I am trying to insert multiple records in `initState()` into the database using for loop as below:

```
void _insertManyAttendees() async {
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfPeople; i++) {
      Map<String, dynamic> row = {'name': 'Attendee $i', 'billId': billId};
      await LocalStorageService.instance.insert(row, 'attendees');
    }
  }
```

However the function above only inserts one record to the database when it actually supposed to insert multiple records.

my `initState()` function:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // 1. Get number of attendees
    numberOfPeople =
        Provider.of<BillData>(context, listen: false).numberOfPeople;

    // 2. ID of new record in database
    billId = Provider.of<BillData>(context, listen: false).id;
    debugPrint('inserted Row ID in input_attendees_screen: $billId');

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      // 3. Create new records in ATTENDEES table based on number of people
      _insertManyAttendees();

      // 4. Find all ATTENDEES based on billId
      _findManyAttendees(billId);

      _findAllAttendees();
    });
  }
```

`_findManyAttendees(billId)` always return only 1 record during the initial insertion but in the next run, it always return the correct number of records.

Wondering what went wrong. Many thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: can you check data on console if it is updating ?  also try `Future<void >_insertManyAttendees()`  and then use await while calling this method.  `(_) async{ await _insertManyAttendees()` if data depended on state variable, call setState afterward

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Thanks. It's working now. I guess I would need to more help in Future, Async and Await.

Comment: You can check  https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

Comment: Where are you getting the context in the initState?

Answer (score 1):

Include `Future<void>`:

```
Future<void> _insertManyAttendees() async {
  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfPeople; i++) {
    Map<String, dynamic> row = {'name': 'Attendee $i', 'billId': billId};
    await LocalStorageService.instance.insert(row, 'attendees');
  }
}
```

Call the method using await:

```
await _insertManyAttendees();
```